# MySQL creates excess duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I have a big array of data, which I want to insert into a DB.
Each element of the array represents another array for a row in my DB.
For each element I create an `ActiveRecord` instance.
There can be as much as 10K (and more) elements and I insert them into the DB by `cron`. Before each insert my ActiveRecord runs validation and makes a few SELECTs.

But sometimes I get duplicates in the DB. To simplify, I have the next array of data:

```
Field1           Field2         Field3
field1Value1     field2Value1   field3Value1
field1Value2     field2Value2   field3Value2
field1Value3     field2Value3   field3Value3
field1Value4     field2Value4   field3Value4
```

And in my DB I can get something like this:

```
id   Field1          Field2         Field3          time
1    field1Value1    field2Value1   field3Value1    2013-11-11 17:17:40
2    field1Value2    field2Value2   field3Value2    2013-11-11 17:17:40
3    field1Value4    field2Value4   field3Value4    2013-11-11 17:17:40
4    field1Value2    field2Value2   field3Value2    2013-11-11 17:17:40
5    field1Value3    field2Value3   field3Value3    2013-11-11 17:17:40
```

In this case the row with `value 2` was inserted twice. Also pay attention to the row with `value 4` which was inserted right after the row with `value 2`.

The problem is these cases are occasional, I can't find a pattern here. I tried using transactions but it didn't solve the problem.

In my PHP code I have just a loop which creates a new ActiveRecord instance. There's no way for a row to be inserted twice. So the problem must be in MySQL.

Comment: Provide code. This is useless.

Comment: It's more likely the problem is in your code. Imposible t oanswer without seeing th code

Comment: I can't provide the code. It contains in many classes and every class is nearly one thousand lines.
I just wanted to know if the problem may be caused by MySQL (maybe wrong configuration). If there's no way for this, I will double-check my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always recommend maintaining data integrity at the database level if possible.  If you should never have duplicate values for the three columns as stated above then add a unique index for those three columns on the database table.  If the script is looping and inserting data it will fail when the unique index is violated and it will prevent the situation.  That is the best advice I can provide without seeing the code that is making the inserts.

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON table(field1, field2, field3);

Comment: Thank you, Derek. It's the best way to prevent duplicates.